# empty mysql database and keep the tables structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to empty a database without losing the fields inside each tables. there is about 26 tables they each have numerous fields. any ideas on which method is better to achieve the wanted results.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are many delete constraints?

Answer (score 7):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table1`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `table2`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `table3`;
...
TRUNCATE TABLE `table26`;
```

(ps. replace `tableX` with your actual table names)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

if you have forgein key constraints on them. Or else drop the forgein key constraints and add them back if you still want to use the TRUNCATE statements.